# functional expression not work as column name in R

Tags: r, string

I try to add a new column to a data frame, with a specified column name.

This works:

```
dat = data.frame(x1 = 1:10,
                 x2 = 101:110,
                 x3 = 1:2,
                 x4 = 2:1)

cbind(dat, 'x10' = 1:10)
```

Result:

```
   x1  x2 x3 x4 x10
1   1 101  1  2   1
2   2 102  2  1   2
3   3 103  1  2   3
4   4 104  2  1   4
5   5 105  1  2   5
6   6 106  2  1   6
7   7 107  1  2   7
8   8 108  2  1   8
9   9 109  1  2   9
10 10 110  2  1  10
```

but using a functional expression as the column name not work

```
cbind(dat, paste0('x10', '_flag') = 1:10)
```

> Error: unexpected '=' in "cbind(dat, paste0('x10', '_flag') ="

I was thinking of

```
column_name = paste0('x10', '_flag')
cbind(dat, column_name = 1:10)
```

but it will take "column_name" as the column name, rather than the string it refers to (thanks @42- for correcting me)

How to let R know `paste0()` is just a string? I tried `as.character(paste0())` and it didn't work. Any help's appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately the second method will not interpret the `column_name` so you will end up with `dat$column_name` being 1:10 rather than what you hoped for. The expressions for names of arguments do not get interpreted in pairlists given to functions. You can get interpretation of expressions that get evaluated to character values with `assign` (in the first argument position)  but it ends up being a very bulky sort of code and generally means there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `cbind`, you should learn to use `"["`, since it does accept calculated column names in the j-argument position (after the first comma):

```
> dat[ , paste0('x10', '_flag') ] = 1:10
> dat
   x1  x2 x3 x4 x10_flag
1   1 101  1  2        1
2   2 102  2  1        2
3   3 103  1  2        3
4   4 104  2  1        4
5   5 105  1  2        5
6   6 106  2  1        6
7   7 107  1  2        7
8   8 108  2  1        8
9   9 109  1  2        9
10 10 110  2  1       10
```

This is equivalent to a similar strategy with "[["

```
dat[[ paste0('x10', '_flag') ]] = 1:10
```

Note: this avoids unfortunate newbie efforts to get calculated column names assigned using `$`